# Sort numbers ignoring an numerical identifier

Tags: python, list

I need to sort an array of numbers, and quickly used `sorted()` for the easy approche when I noticied my numbers also contains an numerical identifier before it

That list for example:

```
"0 199.900",
"1 174.500",
"2 350.000",
"3 1.100.000",
...
```

and when I `sorted()` it, I discovered that my task would not be that easy

```
"0 199.900",
"1 174.500",
"10 385.000",
"100 130.000",
"1000 525.000",
...
```

Many ideas approched my mind, such as reading each line character by character until I find the space between the ID and the number and then sort it and write it down the file.

The thing is that the list usually contains 1000 to 5000 numbers and would be unpratical to re-write all the file when I find a new lowest number. Even further in the problem, I cannot discard the ID, in fact I need to keep the same exact ID when the list is sorted
Example:

```
1 199.000
...
32 189.000
...
```

Would need to be:

```
32 189.000
1 199.00
...
```

Any ideas on how I could solve it? I can deal with the case using an array inside of the python script before it gets writen into the file or sort the already created file, any approche would fit.

Comment: Ignoring the initial number is not difficult with the `key` argument. But it's not clear how your numbers should be sorted since they don't appear to be regular floats. For example: does `1.100.000` come before or after `1.20.000` or `999.9`?

Comment: All the numbers are integers, the . are only cosmetical but sadly they need to remain there

Comment: @Mark I assume these aren't meant to be floats;  `.` is being used here as the European-style thousands separator.

Comment: As 1.100.000 is 1 million and a hundred thousand

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. Thanks @JohnGordon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a custom sort key function that ignores the first number, and also ignores periods.

```
def mysortkey(s):
    # grab the second number
    num = s.split()[1]
    # make a new string, omitting periods
    num = num.replace('.', '')
    # return integer value of the string
    return int(num)

sorted_list = sorted(mylist, key=mysortkey)
```

Comment: Surely `num = num.replace('.', '')` is simpler than `join`ing a genexpr?

Comment: The code looks all fine but when I tried it, somehow it is sorting it by hex 16? Or I am crazy?
The outcome was
`"0 174.500", "1 428.000", "10 357.000", "100 269.000", "101 259.900",`

Comment: @ShadowRanger Good call.  I've updated the code.

Comment: @gustavomatteo This code works for me.  However I did make some assumptions about the format of the input list.  Can you edit the original question to show the actual list?  That output looks like it is sorting on the string value of the first number, which shouldn't happen.

Comment: The code is perfect and the error was on me, I forgot to remove the sorted() from
`json.dump(sorted(sortedPrice), f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)`  and I was messing everything

Answer (score 1):

I think that when you had split string into ID and value like above, you can turn it into a dictionary with ID is a key and value as value. After that, you sort dictionary with key=value

```
dictionary = dict({1: 6, 2: 4, 3: 10, 5: 1})
print(sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))
# Output: [(5, 1), (2, 4), (1, 6), (3, 10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to keep the values in a string format and you want to sort on the leading number in the string can do the following:

```
str_list = ["0 199.900",
            "1 174.500",
            "10 385.000",
            "100 130.000",
            "1000 525.000",
            "32 189.000"]

#use list comprehension to break up the strings into two separate numbers
nested_list = [sublist.split() for sublist in str_list]

#sort based on the first number, converting the string into an integer
nested_list.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[0]))

#join the strings back together into their original format
sorted_str_list = [' '.join(sublist) for sublist in nested_list]

print(sorted_str_list)

['0 199.900',
 '1 174.500',
 '10 385.000',
 '32 189.000',
 '100 130.000',
 '1000 525.000']
```

Comment: Good code, but you swapped the number that needed to be sorted. It is the second column. But thanks, that helped :)